# MVC Validation does not seem to work for text fields but is fine with numeric fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I seem to be having a problem with my model validation. The 'Title' field validation does not seem to be working, whereas the 'Price' validation seems to work okay.
Also, on other pages the validation seems to work okay on text fields, it's just this page I'm having a problem with. Been looking at it for way too long so I'd really appreciate any help.

My Model

```
public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is Required Field")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        
        public string Color { get; set; }
        
       
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is Required Field")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

    }
```

The View

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Title:</label></td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Title)</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Color:</label></td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Color)</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Color)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Price:</label></td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Price)</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price)</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

The Action

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(Product model)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

I have ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled set to true in my web.config file.

I also have the following in the header file

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add a ValidationSummary

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
.....
}
```

and since decimal is not nullable it is 0 by default, so reqiered will not work since it is not null. Because it is a  price field, try this , it is used for currency

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.?\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Wrong format")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry @Serge but it didn't work. The Title field still refuses to validate if left blank